# System exception occurred during an invocation on EJB caused by illegal argument exception

Tags: jpa, jsf

I'm not too sure what is wrong with it. It keeps on showing these error messages. Seems like there are some null values but i can't seem to identify and correct those issues. Can anyone help to take a look?

Update: I'm thinking the issue should either in the managedbean or post construct method but i can't seem to find out why..

**Summarized Error Message**

```
System exception occurred during an invocation on EJB RequestController, 
method: public entity.Request ejb.session.stateless.RequestController.retrieveRequestByRequestId(java.lang.Long) throws exception.RequestNotFoundException

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
```

**Post Construct In DeleteRequestManagedBean**

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {

    requestId = (Long)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("request");
    try {
        request = requestControllerLocal.retrieveRequestByRequestId(requestId);
    }
//Removed some irrelevant codes
```

**Delete Request Method In DeleteRequestManagedBean**

```
public void deleteRequest() {

    requestControllerLocal.deleteRequest(requestId); 
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Request has been successfully deleted: ", null));
}
```

**Button to delete request in xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Remove" icon ="fa fa-fw fa-remove" styleClass="p-btnDelete" actionListener="#{deleteRequestManagedBean.deleteRequest}"/>
```

**Delete Request Method in RequestController (Stateless Sessionbean)**

```
@Override
public void deleteRequest(Long requestId) throws RequestNotFoundException, DeleteRequestException {
//Removed some irrelevant codes
Request requestToDelete = retrieveRequestByRequestId(requestId);
requestToDelete.getCategory().getRequests().remove(requestToDelete);
        em.remove(requestToDelete);
}
```

Please feel free to let me know if there are any other information you need. Thank you!

Comment: you are sending the PK of the entity as null

Comment: Hi there, could you tell me which part? I am trying to get the id of the request at the page before i try to delete it but it seems like i'm failing.

Comment: Check the requestId value and verify requestToDelete object values ?

Comment: When i tried printing requestId, it throws null pointer exception. But i thought i'm using the post construct to load the request already? Am i doing the post construct wrongly?

Comment: Check your flash object in  PostConstruct  Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that both my managedbean and xhtml page has issues.

I have to use **getAttribute()** instead and get the attribute "postRToDelete" from the xhtml page. Without getting retrieving this, it keeps on giving me the null pointers, illegal argument exceptions.

Here it is for the benefit for those who made the same mistake as me.

**DeleteRequestManagedbean**

```
Request request = (Request) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("postRToDelete");
```

**xhtml page**

```
<p:commandButton value="Delete" icon ="fa fa-fw fa-remove" styleClass="p-btnDelete" actionListener="#{profileManagedBean.deletePostedRequest}" update="@form">

<!--attribute from here-->
<f:attribute name="postRToDelete" value="#{postedReq}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```